# Remove SPSS from input_list=['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS'] and add 'SPARK' in its place

Tags: python, list

I want to remove SPSS from this list `['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS']` and add `'SPARK'` in its place.

Input:

```
['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS']
```

Desired output:

```
['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPARK']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use remove() and append() method to add and remove element from the list respectively.

```
input_list=['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS']
input_list.remove('SPSS')
input_list.append('SPARK') 
print(input_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `remove` and `append` method as:

```
input_list=['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS']
input_list.remove('SPSS')
input_list.append('SPARK')
print(input_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
input_list =['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPSS']

input_list[3] ="SPARK"

print(input_list)
 
output :['SAS', 'R', 'PYTHON', 'SPARK']
```